# How to create a Task belonging to an Iteration using Rally Api and .NET

Tags: rally, agile-central

I am new to the Rally API and just having some trouble creating a Task using the Rally.RestApi library.  I need to create a Task (using .NET) and associate it with a User Story (in which the User Story belongs to a certain Iteration).

Do I have to get the User Story first, then add a Task to it?  How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All objects in Rally have a unique url called a ref.
You just need the story's ref to associate the two:

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("myuser@company.com", "password",
    "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.27");
DynamicJsonObject newTask = new DynamicJsonObject();
newTask["Name"] = "My New Task";
newTask["WorkProduct"] = "/hierarchicalrequirement/12345"; //your story ref here
CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create("task", newTask);
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for prompt answer. Just wondering, should the last line be restApi.Create("tasks", newTask); ?

Comment: Good catch!  I adapted that snippet from a defect creation example and missed the last line.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: what fields (other than toCreate["Name"]) are available for Task creation?

Comment: FYI - to query for User Story by Iteration Name and User Story Name, use: rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.27/hierarchicalrequirement?query=((Name = "User Story Name Here") and (Iteration.Name = "Iteration_Name_Here"))&fetch=true

Comment: Check out the interactive Web Services API documentation here:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

You can browse all the available objects exposed and their fields and even test out queries against them.

Comment: I am getting an error on the Create method.  Error is: KeyNotFoundException, The given key was not present in the dictionary.